# Simplifying a Boolean Expression with two additional conditions

Tags: boolean-algebra

Problem:

Given that $$ A \cdot B = 0$$ and $$A + B = 1$$ use algebraic manipulation to prove that:
$$ (A + C) \cdot( \overline A + B ) \cdot (B + C) = B \cdot C$$

Answer:
First, I will rewrite the left hand side without the operator $$ \cdot $$. That is, I will write $$ AB $$ to mean $$A \cdot B$$.

\begin{align*}
(A + C)( \overline A + B ) (B + C) &= ( 0 + \overline A C + AB + BC ) (B + C) \\
(A + C)( \overline A + B ) (B + C) &= ( 0 + \overline A C + 0 + BC ) (B + C) = ( \overline A C + BC )( B + C) \\
(A + C)( \overline A + B ) (B + C) &= B( \overline A C + BC ) + C( \overline A C + BC ) \\
(A + C)( \overline A + B ) (B + C) &=  \overline A BC + BC + C( \overline A C + BC ) \\
(A + C)( \overline A + B ) (B + C) &= \overline A BC + BC + \overline A C + BC \\
(A + C)( \overline A + B ) (B + C) &= \overline A BC + BC + \overline A C \\
(A + C)( \overline A + B ) (B + C) &= \overline A BC + \overline A C + BC \\
(A + C)( \overline A + B ) (B + C) &= \overline A C + BC \\
\end{align*}
I think I am on the right track, but I do not know how to finish solving the problem.
Thanks,
Bob

Comment: How did you go from (0+!AC+AB+BC) to (0+!AC+0+BC) on the right side of step 1 to step 2?

Comment: @MichaelKaras We are given that AB is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a super long detour for a simple result:

1. A·B = 0 implies that *at most* one of A, B is true
2. A+B = 1 implies that *at least* one of A, B is true
3. This implies that *exactly* one of A, B is true.
4. This implies that \$\overline A = B\$.

Then

\begin{align}
(A + C) \cdot( \overline A + B ) \cdot (B + C) 
&=(\overline B +C)\cdot(B+B)\cdot (B+C)\\
&=B(\overline B +C)(B+C)\\
&=(B\overline B + BC)(B+C)\\
&=(0+BC)(B+C)\\
&= BCB + BCC\\
&=BC\\
&\overset!=BC 
\end{align}